# Using Python mock with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, api, mocking

I'm mocking some data returned from a REST API for my unit tests, using the very cool mock library: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to mock something with multiple, nested dictionaries.

```
data = r.json()['result']['rows'][0]['values']
```

I tried using the dictionaries example from the docs with little success.  What I'm essentially trying to accomplish is this:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m.json()['result']['rows'][0].return_value = {'values': 'myvalue'}
>>> m.json()['result']['rows'][0]['values']  # doesn't work
myvalue
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Usually you are not replacing data of native types like what could come out of JSON with a mock. Use mocks for objects, classes, callables. If you need testing data mock the function that returns it to return your test data as JSON. Libs like `requests-mock` might be helpful.

Comment: requests-mock looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I've learned you can set the return value to return another property which itself has a return value.  This is doing what I want:

```
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> m.return_value.json.return_value = {'status': 'ok!'}
>>> r = m()
>>> r.json()
{'status': 'okay!'}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this helps with `r.json()['result']['rows'][0]['values']` from the question, since this result doesn't have a deeply nested object.